# How to add alias with model in CActiveDataProivder yii

Tags: php, yii

I have User model with "type" attribute. and Product model with "title". Here is my code.

```
$criteria = new  CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('type = "ABC"');    
$criteria->mergeWith ( array (
            'with' => 'products'
        ) );

$criteria->mergeWith ( array (
            'condition' => "`products`.title LIKE '". $model->title ."'",
            'together' => true
        ) );

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
```

It is giving following error:-

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'type' in where clause is ambiguous
```

My question is, how to add  alias for User model so the User.type = "ABC" using above approch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$criteria = new  CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('t.type' => "ABC");    
$criteria->with= array('products'=>array('on'=>"title LIKE '$model->title'"));

$criteria->together=true;

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
```

if does not work please paste full error with whole query

Comment: Thanks for your response and yes it is working with t.type but what if we explicitly want to add alias for User table.

Comment: Sorry brother, can't help you there. Yii requires these alias to create nested objects, so i never tried to challenge it's cool functions.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$criteria = new  CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('table_name.type = "ABC"');    
$criteria->mergeWith ( array (
            'with' => 'products'
        ) );

$criteria->mergeWith ( array (
            'condition' => "`products`.title LIKE '". $model->title ."'",
            'together' => true
        ) );

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have tried this but its not working.
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.type' in 'where clause'

Comment: are you sure that your table name is: User?  maybe in mysql database the name of table is user??? don't forget casesensetive in mysql.

Comment: Yeah the table name is "User"